# Jenkins Environment variables giving null values as output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to access github `env.CHANGE_AUTHOR` environment variable from groovy script in jenkins multibranch pipeline.

While some of the environment variables are giving correct output (for example `env.JOB_NAME`,`env.BRANCH_NAME`), others like `env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME` ,`env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL` are giving `null` values.

Has anybody come across this issue before? What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested with the github org plugin which uses the multi branch plugin, created a PR and the CI job it does has those env vars present.  Using a Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
 echo "${env.getEnvironment()}"
}
```

In my Jenkins PR build console I see amongst others:

```
CHANGE_AUTHOR:rawlingsj, CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME:James Rawlings, CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL:rawlingsj80@gmail.com, CHANGE_ID:1, CHANGE_TARGET:master, CHANGE_TITLE:test msg, CHANGE_URL:https://github.com/rawlingsj/multi-branch-test/pull/1
```

Just a wild guess.. do you have your `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` set on the commit in the PR?  If so it's worth mentioning which version of the multi branch plugin you're using and upgrade to the latest if its old.

Comment: I am using latest version 1.1 of multibranch plugin.....I have git config user.name also set on the commit......If I use your Jenkins File code as mentioned above...the Error coming is::      Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment.....And there is no change in output too...env.CHANGE_AUTHOR IS giving null

Comment: That's the [script approval](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin#ScriptSecurityPlugin-User%E2%80%99sguide) related to running groovy scripts in pipelines.  You can run in a sandbox which that links describes or approve the script in the jenkins ui at `http://your.jenkins.com/scriptApproval/`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to an existing bug where the git environment variables are always null:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36436

It looks like it was very recently fixed in this PR:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/492